# Vue not Defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have been struggling this error for a while now. I've tried multiple ways and none of them work. All I am trying to do is to get this simple component working. Someone help please. :)

```js
<script>
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#main",
  data: function(){
          return {
          search: '',
          customers: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Something', },
            { id: '2', name: 'Something else', },
            { id: '3', name: 'Something random', },
            { id: '4', name: 'Something crazy', }
          ]};
  },
  computed:
  {
      filteredCustomers:function()
      {
         var self=this;
         return this.customers.filter(function(cust){return cust.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.search.toLowerCase())>=0;});
         //return this.customers;
      }
  }
  });
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div id="main">
Search: <input type="text" v-model="search"/>   
<div v-bind:v-for="customer in filteredCustomers">
 <span>{{customer.name}}</span>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Get it working how? How is anyone supposed to know how it should work?

Comment: I don't expect it to magically work. What I mean is it's not working on my end. I am trying to create a Search Filter. But the real issue has been the error. I am unsure how to resolve it. "Vue is not Defined".

Comment: Did you include Vue like so https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include?

Comment: You probably havn't used the vue CDN link in the correct page. How are you injecting vue into your web app?

Comment: Just did now, throws me two errors.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

Cannot find element: #main

Comment: Usually I have been installing it through using npm commands. I never had to use a link.

Comment: I am using Vuetify if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include the Vue library.
One way of doing so is including using `<script>` as described in Vue's [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Direct-lt-script-gt-Include).

Comment: This works but now I got two other errors to resolve. I may just post the other two errors on another post since it's a bit unrelated. Thank you for your help. :)